# Yocto: Change ownership of /usr/lib

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

How can I change ownership of **/usr/lib** directory and all libraries inside for a specific user?

I tried to write a custom bb recipe without success.

```
SUMMARY = "Change /usr/lib ownership."
LICENSE = "MIT"

FILES_${PN} = "${libdir}\*"

do_install () {
        chown user1:group1 ${D}${libdir}
}
```

I also try use **${libdir}** instead **/usr/lib**, but without success. How can I access correctly **/usr/lib**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to change it during yocto compilation because the filesystem is built at the end of the process. There are two ways to achieve it. The first is to add **chmod** in the system image installation script.
The second one is to prepare a system service and bash script, which can check the owner and set the current one if necessary.

*owner-updater.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=Directory Owner Updater
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/update-owner
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*update-owner*

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=user_name
DIR_PATH="/usr/lib"
DIR_OWNER="$(stat --format '%U' $DIR_PATH)"
DIR_GROUP="$(stat --format '%G' $DIR_PATH)"

if [ "$(id -u $DIR_OWNER)" -eq "$(id -u $USER)" ] &&
   [ "$(id -g $DIR_GROUP)" -eq "$(id -g $USER)" ]; then
    echo Correct owner
else
    echo Incorrect owner
fi
    chown -R [user_name/user_id]:[group_name/group_id] /usr/lib
```